# Comma between attribute tuples

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists

Consider the following sample sentence:

> *Peter is pretty tolerant and mostly good-humoured, free-spirited and good to talk to.*

I want to say that Peter has all four attributes ("*tolerant*", "*good-humoured*", "*free-spirited*" and "*good to talk to*"), however for poetic reasons I split the series of four attributes in two attribute tuples ("*pretty tolerant and mostly good-humoured*" and "*free-spirited and good to talk to*").

In this circumstances, is the comma between "*mostly good-humoured*" and "*free-spirited*" correct? And does the poetic sub-grouping makes sense?

Comment: This reads to me as Peter is pretty A and mostly B, C and D. I'd use a super-comma (which looks exactly like a semicolon) if I really felt I had to.

Comment: "*Peter is pretty A and mostly B; C and D.*"? - The semicolon looks weird to me. But I get your point that the "*mostly*" could be understood as applicable to B, to C and to D. - Not sure what to do...

Comment: I would not use the semi-colon.  You could simply move "mostly good-humored" into the fourth position. Depending on what you really want to say, you could move the first pair to follow the second pair, or you could have your couples divorce and remarry in a different configuration.

Comment: For those who don't like super-comma usage, perhaps they're happier with a sentence fragment (which few oppose per se nowadays). Peter is pretty tolerant and mostly good-humoured. Free-spirited and good to talk to.

Comment: If you don't feel like it changes the subtle meaning too much, you can switch it around a bit more: “Peter is free-spirited (and/,) good to talk to, pretty tolerant and mostly good-humoured”. That is at least quite unambiguous.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, could you please select the check mark next to it? If you feel that my answer was not the one you were looking for, could you please edit your posting to clarify so that we can reopen it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is fine as it stands:

1. Peter is pretty tolerant and mostly good-humoured, free-spirited and good to talk to.

Obsequious obedience to simplistic style-guide directions can kill the magic of a a carefully crafted artistic phrase, leaving you with nothing but a dead corpse that stirs no passion. It can also subtly change the meaning into something you might not have intended:

2. Peter is pretty tolerant, mostly good-humoured, free-spirited, and good to talk to.
3. Peter is pretty tolerant, mostly good-humoured and free-spirited, and good to talk to.
4. Peter is pretty, tolerant, and mostly good-humoured, free-spirited and good to talk to.
5. Peter is pretty, tolerant and mostly good-humoured, and free-spirited and good to talk to.

Say what you want to say in the way that sounds best to you.